# Should we copy answers from the GNU GPL FAQ

Tags: discussion

(Follow up to [Should we copy questions from the GNU GPL FAQ](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330/should-we-copy-questions-from-the-gnu-gpl-faq)):

I noticed the answers copy verbatim of entries of the [GNU GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html).

Should we get content for this website by simply mirroring content from official FAQs?

Are we even allowed to do this copyright-wise? The page the quote comes from is licensed under CC-BY-ND 4.0, while all stackexchange content is licensed under CC-BY-SA 3.0. AFAIK licenses are not compatible because SA allows changes while ND does not.

Answer (score 8):

No. An answer can cite a source, but it should contain an explanation in own words.

Comment: What about a simple link to the FAQ?

Comment: Wouldn't change anything. Link-only answers are bad anyway, you should provide your own insight. If you support that with a link, a citation or both doesn't matter.

Comment: OK. So what about a link *in a comment*?

Comment: You can always put links as comments, that's one possible usage of them.

Comment: So let's do this :)

Comment: @EricGärtner Let's not do this, because that's incredibly inappropriate.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Why do you not want to put a link into a comment?

Comment: @EricGärtner It's simple. Answering in comments is not good, and it makes no sense. We have a voting system, and answering in comments nullify's that. It's horrible for the fiscal health of the site

Comment: @EricGärtner: Instead just go with the way I proposed: make useful answers with own words, supported with links and citations from applicable sources.

Answer (score 6):

That's plagarism.

Don't just copy answers from other places, just go ahead and make answers of your own. What you can do is ***cite these sources to support your answers.***